# Get the first element of each tuple in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

An SQL query gives me a list of tuples, like this:

```
[(elt1, elt2), (elt1, elt2), (elt1, elt2), (elt1, elt2), (elt1, elt2), ...]
```

I'd like to have all the first elements of each tuple. Right now I use this:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
res_list = []
for row in rows:
    res_list += [row[0]]
```

But I think there might be a better syntax to do it. Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res_list = [x[0] for x in rows]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> rows = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> [x[0] for x in rows]
[1, 3, 5]
>>>
```

---

Alternately, you could use unpacking instead of `x[0]`:

```
res_list = [x for x,_ in rows]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> [x for x,_ in lst]
[1, 3, 5]
>>>
```

Both methods practically do the same thing, so you can choose whichever you like.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found documentation on the syntax `x,_`. Do you know where I could find some?

Comment: @Creak - `x,_` is just using tuple unpacking.  And you are right, the documentation on this is hard to come by.  I found this [link](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html) and this [one](http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/630101/Learn-to-Program-using-Python-Unpacking-Tuples.htm#Introduction) which should explain how it works.  Also, the `_` is just a normal variable.  I could have done `x,y` and got the same results.  However, I did not because it is a Python convention to use a `_` for variables that are only placeholders.

Comment: Ok, I thought `_` was a special character to say "1 or more elements". That would have been excellent ;)

Comment: The list comprehension you give will only work when the tuples have exactly two entries. In python3, you could do `[x for x, *the_rest in rows]`, where the `*` really is the special syntax for "the rest of the elements of the tuple". For a list comprehension that will work in python2, use `[iter(x).next() for x in rows]`

Answer (score 43):

The functional way of achieving this is to unzip the list using:

```
sample = [(2, 9), (2, 9), (8, 9), (10, 9), (23, 26), (1, 9), (43, 44)]
first,snd = zip(*sample)
print(first,snd)
```

(2, 2, 8, 10, 23, 1, 43) (9, 9, 9, 9, 26, 9, 44)

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to use list comprehension by some reasons, you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> rows = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> map(itemgetter(1), rows)
[2, 4, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use list comprehension:

```
res_list = [i[0] for i in rows]
```

This should make the trick

Answer (score 9):

```
res_list = [x[0] for x in rows]
```

c.f. http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

For a discussion on why to prefer comprehensions over higher-order functions such as `map`, go to http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196.