# Selecting part of a string in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that displays the names of the planets in the list Planets in descending order by their position from the Sun.

As you can see below, I've managed to figure out how to sort the different planets by their position from the Sun (third value in the strings) but I can't figure out how to remove the numbers and just display the text, as it displays the whole strings from the list and not just the name of the planet which is what I would want ideally. Any ideas?

```
planet_tuples=[
    ("Mercury",75,1),
    ("Venus",460,2),
    ("Mars",140,4),
    ("Earth",510,3),
    ("Jupiter",62000,5),
    ("Neptune",7640,8),
    ("Saturn",42700,6),
    ("Uranus",8100,7),
    ]
s=(sorted(planet_tuples,key=lambda planet: planet[2],reverse=True))
s.remove(planet_tuples[])
print (s)
```

Comment: So you just want the names? `[i[0] for i in s]` after you sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the first element of each tuple in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412258/get-the-first-element-of-each-tuple-in-a-list-in-python)

Comment: That worked, thanks! Can't understand why I didn't think of that sooner!

Comment: @chrisz, my bad, I must have not seen this in the similar questions while I was writing mine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract first element of `tuple` with `list comprehension`:

```
print ([x[0] for x in s])
```

Result:

```
['Neptune', 'Uranus', 'Saturn', 'Jupiter', 'Mars', 'Earth', 'Venus', 'Mercury']
```

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding.`

Comment: `sum(s, ()))` *why are you suggesting an antipattern*? *never* use `sum` to concatenate sequences. That is O(N^2). Use `itertools.chain` or a flattening list-comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was just trying other alternatives, may be not good idea, will remove it.

Comment: Flattening and then slicing isn't crazy - it can be O(N), but not if your flattening operation is O(N^2)